# Type safe way of narrowing type of arrays by length when noUncheckedIndexedAccess is true

Tags: typescript, narrowing

Given a function that takes a single `string[]` argument `myArray`.

If I evaluate the `.length` property and that property is greater than 0, then (assuming my variable isn't `any` in disguise) its *impossible* for `myArray[0]` to be undefined. However, if I enable `noUncheckedIndexedAccess`, its type will be `string | undefined`

```
const myFunc = (myArray: string[]) => {
   if(myArray.length > 0) {
     const foo = myArray[0] // now typed at 'string | undefined'
   }
}
```

Now I can change the if statement to evaluate `myArray[0]`, and `undefined` is removed from the type as you'd expect. But what if I now want to check that the length of the array is greater than 6. I don't want to have to do the same thing for indexes 0-5 to correctly narrow down the type. e.g:

```
const myFunc = (myArray: string[]) => {
   if(myArray[0] && myArray[1] && myArray[2] && myArray[3] && myArray[4] && myArray[5]) {
      const foo = myArray[0] // now typed at 'string', but this is uggggly
   }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of narrowing the type based on the *length* of the array or am I going to have to look into contributing to the TypeScript codebase?

Comment: You can write a user-defined type guard function that has this effect, although it is kinda weird and has edge cases.  So instead of `arr.length >= 6` you’d write `hasLengthAtLeast(arr, 6)`. If that sounds like something you want to see I could write up an answer when I get a chance. Otherwise I’d say the answer here is just “no”.  Let me know.

Comment: tbh, I had considered the type guard option. If I'm honest I was looking to confirm my belief that this just isn't implemented right now.

Might be a fun excuse to start digging into the tsc codebase

Comment: @BenWainwright can your please provide a reproducible error in the playground ?

Comment: Well... no. My question doesn't ask anything about any errors. I think I've been clear enough.

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/WkjXjm) is the type guard function I would possibly suggest; I'll probably write up an answer saying that what you want isn't possible.  With links to [microsoft/TypeScript#38000](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38000) which is listed as "too complex", so I doubt you'd get far with working on this yourself.  Answer forthcoming in a bit.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As you suspected, TypeScript does not automatically narrow the type of an array based upon a check of its `length` property.  This has been suggested before at [microsoft/TypeScript#38000](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38000), which is marked as "too complex".  It looks like it had been suggested prior to that, at [microsoft/TypeScript#28837](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28837), which is still open and marked as "awaiting more feedback".  Possibly you could go to that issue and leave feedback as to why such a thing would be helpful to you and why the current solutions aren't sufficient, but I don't know that it'll have much effect.  Either way I doubt that the TS team is taking pull requests to implement such a feature right now.

In the absence of any automatic narrowing, you could instead write a [user defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that has the effect you want.  Here's one possible implementation:

```
type Indices<L extends number, T extends number[] = []> =
    T['length'] extends L ? T[number] : Indices<L, [T['length'], ...T]>;

type LengthAtLeast<T extends readonly any[], L extends number> = 
  Pick<Required<T>, Indices<L>>

function hasLengthAtLeast<T extends readonly any[], L extends number>(
    arr: T, len: L
): arr is T & LengthAtLeast<T, L> {
    return arr.length >= len;
}
```

The `Indices<L>` type is intended to take a single, relatively small, non-negative, integral numeric [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `L` and return a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the numeric indices of an array with length `L`.  Another way to say this is that `Indices<L>` should be a union of the nonnegative whole numbers less than `L`.  Observe:

```
type ZeroToNine = Indices<10>
// type ZeroToNine = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

This type works by leveraging [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) along with [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to walk from `0` up to `L`.  Recursive types tend to work fine until they don't, and one big caveat here is that things will be weird or even throw errors if you pass in an `L` that is too large, or fractional, or negative, or `number`, or a union.  That's a big caveat for this approach.

Next, `LengthAtLeast<T, L>` takes an array type `T` and a length `L`, and returns an object which is known to have properties at all the indices of an array of at least length `L`.  Like this:

```
type Test = LengthAtLeast<["a"?, "b"?, "c"?, "d"?, "e"?], 3>
/* type Test = {
    0: "a";
    1: "b";
    2: "c";
} */

type Test2 = LengthAtLeast<string[], 2>
/* type Test2 = {
    0: string;
    1: string;
} */
```

Finally, `hasLengthAtLeast(arr, len)` is the type guard function.  If it returns `true`, then `arr` is narrowed from type `T` to `T & LengthAtLeast<T, L>`.  Let's see it in action:

```
const myFunc = (myArray: string[]) => {
    if (hasLengthAtLeast(myArray, 6)) {
        myArray[0].toUpperCase(); // okay
        myArray[5].toUpperCase(); // okay
        myArray[6].toUpperCase(); // error, possibly undefined
    }
}
```

Looks good.  The compiler is happy to allow you to treat `myArray[0]` and `myArray[5]` as defined, but `myArray[6]` is still possibly undefined.

---

Anyway, if you do decide to go for a type guard, you might want to balance complexity against how much you need to use it.  If you're only checking length a few places, it might be worthwhile just to use a [non-`null` assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) like `myArray[0]!.toUpperCase()` and not worry about getting the compiler to verify type safety for you.

Or, if you have no control over the value of `len`, then you might not want a fragile recursive conditional type, and instead build something more robust but less flexible (like maybe an overloaded type guard that only works for specific `len` values like [in a comment on microsoft/TypeScript#38000](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38000#issuecomment-855348141)).

It all comes down to your use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#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-BIwK-eQ-2nGAFmvLwACoYCbB9oEqfZhGMSgfy-d1gWzXCgIIvQylw0CCMyGAkK8Rs711R8KmfVtlDfYcP3qBgWBCMpEJQtCmMw3EcKoKBaAYUjhBGOpxIaKiaLom8BFENBgCgGhwBgZRnBfO02I7Dju17dUhUHYdRzAcdJx45sBXnfV7A4HBcRIYhKF5EJFUoWkBFYSg3MIEQ2X5AY9LbQyux7GcuCwoQhygFBCDAGBArkVi1GwRUqI9QoMJKNTC2wPAjjIWSJMadhMFi3F2hwHSIHCgz3ygEqphCLRtFxQ4phOSFzm+K4-luQEEG64RQXefqvkuX4bgBR4xsInrVnBD4Btm2Fbn8RFQnCSIYjiRJklSdJCPxD0gA)

Comment: Wow. Super comprehensive answer, thanks!

Comment: Replace `readonly any[]` with `{ length: number, [key: number]: unknown }` to make this work for strings too! The `readonly` is redundant, just in case.

Comment: Sorry, too late to edit, `ArrayLike<unknown>` is more idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer.
However, the type `LengthAtLeast<string[], 2>` doesn't seem to support regular array methods. Example `array.every`

Comment: Right, `LengthAtLeast` does not produce an array type.  If you need it to still be an array type, you should intersect it with the original array type, as shown in the answer with the output of the type guard `hasLengthAtLeast()`.  See [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nl2OeW).  If you need `LengthAtLeast` to be an array type, you could redefine it to be `T & ` the version I have, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRX6Xm).

Answer (score 2):

> If I evaluate the `.length` property and that property is greater than 0, then (assuming my variable isn't `any` in disguise) its impossible for `myArray[0]` to be `undefined`.

Note that, strictly speaking, this is indeed possible for ***sparse arrays***. As a counterexample:

```
let xs /* : number[] */ = new Array<number>(100);
console.log(xs.length); // -> 100
console.log(xs[0]);     // -> undefined
```

In the code above, `xs`'s `length` property is `100`, greater than zero, and yet `xs[0]` evaluates to `undefined`. This is because `xs` is a *sparse array*.

The `length` property corresponds to the number of elements in a *dense* array. However, if the array is *sparse*, the number of elements is strictly less than the value of the `length` property, and the elements could start at a non-zero index.

Answer (score -3):

One possible workaround:

```js
const [first, second] = myArray
assert(first)
assert(second)

first // can use normally here
```

One advantage is that `assert` can run in development and can be removed in production if you want to skip the runtime cost. Still kind of ugly though.