# Type guard based on function arity

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a function with multiple optional parameters.

Why is there no type guard based on the function arity through the `arguments` keyword and how to solve this without changing the implementation and without ugly casts?

```
function test(arg0?: string, arg1?: string, arg2?: string) {

    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        // I expect arg0 to be of type string instead of string | undefined
    }

    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        // I expect arg0 and arg1 to be of type string instead of string | undefined
    }

    if (arguments.length === 3) {
        // I expect arg0, arg1 and arg2 to be of type string instead of string | undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: `test(undefined);` is a valid call which would make `arguments.length === 1` yet the `arg0` is still `undefined`.

Comment: Hmm indeed I didn't think of this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see `arguments` type:

```js
interface IArguments {
    [index: number]: any;
    length: number;
    callee: Function;
}

interface IArguments {
    /** Iterator */
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<any>;
}
```

As you might have noticed, keyword `arguments` knows nothing about arity of arguments type. From typescript perspective it is not even bound to function context. It just an object with a bunch of unrelated to function arguments properties.

Moreover, `length` property does not act like typeguard. You are unable to infer for example `[string, string]` type just by checking if `length === 2`.
Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69368851/type-safe-way-of-narrowing-type-of-arrays-by-length-when-nouncheckedindexedacces) answer. You will find there appropriate links to github issues and this `hasLengthAtLeast` helper.

Answer (score 1):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70117292/type-guard-based-on-function-arity/70118039#70118039) is quite good, making use of a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to narrow the type.

I would suggest an alternate way, making use of [rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#rest-parameters-and-arguments), like so:

```
function test(...args: string[]) {
  if (args.length === 1) {
    console.log('arg0:', typeof args[0]);
  }

  if (args.length === 2) {
    console.log('arg0:', typeof args[0], 'arg1:', typeof args[1]);
  }

  if (args.length === 3) {
    console.log('arg0:', typeof args[0], 'arg1:', typeof args[1], 'arg2:', typeof args[2]);
  }
}
```

When used with various arguments, we get the following output:

| Input | Compiles? | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `test('one');` | yes | `arg0: string` |
| `test('one', 'two', 'three');` | yes | `arg0: string arg1: string arg2: string` |
| `test(1);` | no | `error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.` |
| `test(undefined);` | no | `error TS2345: Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.` |

One (potentially major) downside of this approach is that the length of the `args` array is not limited. Depending on your use case it could be sufficient to ignore excess arguments, or you could perform a runtime check like so:

```
if (args.length > 3) {
  throw new Error(`Expected 3 arguments, but got ${args.length}`);
}
```

Food for thought.