# Is it possible to design a type guard for an array being empty?

Tags: typescript, types

There are numerous examples of how to design a type guard for an array being NOT empty. For example [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69368851/type-safe-way-of-narrowing-type-of-arrays-by-length-when-nouncheckedindexedacces/69370003#69370003) works great when using [noUncheckedIndexedAccess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess):

```
type Indices<L extends number, T extends number[] = []> = T["length"] extends L
  ? T[number]
  : Indices<L, [T["length"], ...T]>;

export type LengthAtLeast<T extends readonly any[], L extends number> = Pick<
  Required<T>,
  Indices<L>
>;

// Borrowed from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69370003/521097
export function hasLengthAtLeast<T extends readonly any[], L extends number>(
  arr: T,
  len: L
): arr is T & LengthAtLeast<T, L> {
  return arr.length >= len;
}

export function isNotEmpty<T extends readonly any[]>(arr: T): arr is T & LengthAtLeast<T, 1> {
  return hasLengthAtLeast(arr, 1);
}
```

then:

```
let foo = [1, 2, 3];

if (isNotEmpty(foo)) 
  foo[0].toString() // does not error
else 
 foo[0].toString() // does error
```

However to check the inverse of this one must invert the boolean check:

```
let foo = [1, 2, 3];

if (!isNotEmpty(foo)) 
  foo[0].toString(); // now errors
else 
  foo[0].toString(); // now does not error
```

The problem is I think `if (!isNotEmpty(foo))` is a bit ugly to read because it is a double negative.

So the question is, how to define an `isEmpty` type guard so that one can do `if (isEmpty(foo))` and still get the same result as the code snippet shown above? It seems like a trivial problem but all my attempts so far have been thwarted.

I think the main issue is that you cannot assert the inverse of a type guard, you cannot say that something IS NOT something else.

EDIT: I have been asked to provide more examples.

So here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
function logFirstDataElement(data: number[]) {
  // Dont do anything if no data
  if (isEmpty(data)) return;

  // this should not error because data should have been narrowed to 
  // [T, ...T] 
  // that is, it should have at least one element
  console.log(data[0].toString()) 
}
```

It can be achieved by doing the following

```
function logFirstDataElement(data: number[]) {
  // Dont do anything if no data
  if (!isNotEmpty(data)) return;
  console.log(data[0].toString()) 
}
```

But as mentioned above I would rather avoid the "double negative" of `!isNotEmpty(data)`

Comment: Re: Your [update](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73398077/3): asserting to the compiler that an array is not empty does not assert that it has a value at index `0`. Those are different assertions and require different type guards. (e.g. an array can not be empty, but the first 200 elements are `undefined`, with the first not-undefined element appearing only at index 200.)

Comment: Maybe it worth to use `const isFilled=(arr:any[]): arr is [any, ...any[]]=> your code`. Just use two typeguards

Comment: @jsejcksn is that true tho? If you declare your array as `number[]` then arent you asserting that is a contiguous array with ONLY numbers in it?

Comment: @jsejcksn if that is the case then perhaps rather than `isEmpty` I need an `doesNotHaveAFirstElement` or something?

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine if would like to avoid having two type guards in my if-statement if possible

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73398077/is-it-possible-to-design-a-type-guard-for-an-array-being-empty#comment129620934_73398077) @mikeysee Yes, that is true: https://tsplay.dev/wRl9nm

Comment: @mikeysee See my updated answer. It addresses your clarified concern about using a "double negative".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a predicate that sets the array to the empty tuple `[]`:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=3&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgUQLYAcoE9EAUAhgE4lG4BciJApkQCYIA2+RYuA2gLoCU1pcvlSIeiAN4AoRDVpQQJJIIoA6ZrTABzKAAtEAXkOIADAG5JAX0mSICFFETL8+0QEYANIgBMngMzdzSRhgQlRMHFxiMgpeXglpRFswe0QANyJmEFoDR2iuYwDEAHoAKgSZCsqq6oA-BIAVECx1RDwsbIByHg7EOBD1LV1EDuMenSIURDA4RFp1DA0HIgcYMAZaAA9h0ZUCLwAWAE5fOJKiy0k5lGypGSSU9MzslydOAvNqoqKAPQB+SyAA)

> The playground (and code below) uses the compiler option [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) (just like in your question), so even in the `false` branch, you'll have to validate each indexed element to get a non-nullable value.

```ts
function isEmpty (array: readonly any[]): array is [] {
  return array.length === 0;
}

const array = [1, 2, 3];

if (isEmpty(array)) {
  const value = array[0]; /*
                      ~
  Tuple type '[]' of length '0' has no element at index '0'.(2493) */
}
else {
  const value = array[0];
      //^? const value: number | undefined
}
```

---

Update in response to the [updated](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73398077/3) question: This type guard has a *positive* name, so using the [logical NOT (`!`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) to invert it won't result in a *double negative*:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIYGcCCUAyBTDKAeTDwFEAbPAWzzCkQB4AVAPgApUAnL1ATwBciLgQAmCCn0TMA2gF0AlEO68pMdIhnMANIgB0B2XLmIA3gChEwvFBBckK-nqpgA5lGSJWiAAwBucwBfc3NQSFgERAo4VwAxGC50KEoaOgZOHn4hMBBqACM8LnkFM0tEGGBEdgBCNCxcAiSScipaegzVBRKLKysIBCTNYASkkwBeREc+AN7ZqwB6eYA9AH4yqxFbexnEYLL+sEGZYcSoccnM6fXZxdWQvoG4KmcY9hOkvSg4AGUoLhg3OwugFgkA)

```ts
function hasAtLeastOneElement <T>(array: readonly T[]): array is [T, ...T[]] {
  return array.length > 0;
}

function logFirstElement (array: number[]) {
  if (!hasAtLeastOneElement(array)) {
    const [first] = array;
         //^? const first: number | undefined
    return;
  }

  const [first] = array;
       //^? const first: number

  console.log(first.toString());
}
```

Comment: No this is not correct because the non-empty case array value should not be `number | undefined` it should be `number` because we have just asserted that it is NOT empty

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73398077/is-it-possible-to-design-a-type-guard-for-an-array-being-empty/73398433#comment129620215_73398433) @mikeysee No, that's not how [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) works. If you want the behavior that you described, you'll have to disable that compiler option. Here's a link to the same playground with that option disabled: https://tsplay.dev/Nr4v0W

Comment: Well you are able to do the inverse of that as I mentioned in my OP. The type remaining after the isEmpty check should be a tuple with at least one element `[T, ...T]`

Comment: @mikeysee It will be if the input array is such a type (e.g. `const array: [number, ...number[]] = [1, 2, 3];`).

Comment: So its not possible to do it without declaring that ugly tuple type on the "array" variable? 

Seems like it should be possible to simply turn `!isNotEmpty()` into a type guard but I guess not?

Comment: @mikeysee That's right. [Type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) are for narrowing to a single type (not multiple types). Tuples aren't ugly! They (IMO, very elegantly) express that a list always has certain type members at certain indexes.

Comment: Okay well if you would like to add another answer stating that its not possible then I would be happy to mark that one as correct.

Comment: @mikeysee Well, the question that you asked was "Is it possible to design a type guard for an array being empty?", and that's what this answer is in response to.

Comment: @mikeysee try to use `array is never[]` instead of `array is []`. TS infers empty array as `never[]`. Hence if you try to get `array[0]` from empty array you will get `undefined` and TS will complain if you try to call `toString`. It all depends on what type of error you want to get. Please provide more examples when you want to get an error from TS

Comment: Okay I see, well its more nuanced than I could fit in the title. I wanted the narrowed type in the negative case to be a non-empty array as I mentioned in my OP: "and still get the same result as the code snippet shown above?"

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine I have updated the OP with another example to better explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: @jsejcksn okay thanks for your update. Its not exactly the result I was hoping for but I guess its as close as im going to get :) I appreciate all the time you have spent looking into this and being patient with me.

Comment: @mikeysee Glad it works. Maybe a useful read to you: [the beauty of code is the concepts expressed within, not the code itself](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-isnt-beautiful/).